# Integration with Exponentials

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I've tried integration by parts as well as substitution using $u=e^{t}$ but nothing seems to work.

$$\int\left(1-e^{-t}\right) \cdot \exp({e^{t}}) dt$$

Can someone please help? Thanks

Comment: Hint: substitute $u=e^t-t$

Comment: It can be integrated, just as j___d commented.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sometimes I wonder HOW, and really HOW, you can have so many reputations. Your comments are always stupid, and your answers are always useless.

Comment: i have misreaded the question here was it $$\int(1-e^t)e^{e^t}dt$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Factoring, we get:
$$I:= \int \left(1-e^{-t}\right)e^{e^t}\,\mathrm d t = \int \left(e^t-1\right)e^{e^t-t}\,\mathrm d t$$
Now substitute $u=e^t-t$ and thus $\dfrac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm d t}=e^t-1$ to get
$$I=\int e^u\,\mathrm d u=e^u+C=\boxed{e^{e^t-t}+C}$$

Comment: Bingo ! You have good eyes.

Comment: Thank you for solving it

Comment: Thanks @Claude and you're welcome OP!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $1-e^{-t}=f'(t)+g'(t)f(t)$ with  $g(t)=e^t, f(t)=e^{-t}$. see for instance

[Dealing with integrals of the form $\int{e^x(f(x)+f'(x))}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649268/dealing-with-integrals-of-the-form-intexfxfxdx/1975215#1975215)